# Styling Navlink using Tailwind css

Tags: react-router-dom, tailwind-css

I am trying to add tailwind-css to Navlink(react-router-dom). I want to add active style. To add active styles I can use

```
<NavLink to="/faq" activeStyle={{fontWeight: "bold",color: "red"}}>
  FAQs
</NavLink>
```

Is there a way to do this with tailwind-css, I don't want to use css, maybe something like this?

```
<NavLink to="/faq" className={`${active?'font-bold text-red':'text-gray-900'}...`}>
  FAQs
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

V6 of React Router does not have the `activeClassName` property anymore.
Here's how to style NavLink with Tailwind with the new version of ReactRouter and Remix

```
 <NavLink
    to="tasks"
     className={({ isActive }) =>
         isActive ? activeClassName : undefined
        }
     >
     Tasks
  </NavLink>
```

Taken from here https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#navlink

Comment: why the need to use Remix I dont get it?

Comment: @StevenAguilar Remix isnt a requirement, it just that the code snippet is from Remix's docs. Work the same for React.

Answer (score 5):

`NavLink` component has an `activeClassName` property.

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink

Comment: v6 of ReactRouter no longer has this :(

Answer (score 4):

Recently I've been using that aria attribute that NavLink create when it's the current page:

```js
<NavLink
  className="text-white aria-[current=page]:text-blue-400"
  to="/"
>
  Home
</NavLink>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Perfect. I was looking for a simple solution to work with react js and Gatsby js and this is it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

use: **.active**

the **.active** class will be applied automatically to the NavLink component when it matches the current URL path.

**example**

```css
.active {
      @apply text-red-600 ....
 }
```